# display:inline-block and whitespace

Tags: whitespace, css

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EwtaC/1/

The images are styled via display:inline-block. I understand that whitespace somehow has an effect on this.. (for whatever reason) So I removed the whitespace:

```
from <img src="" /> <img src="" />
to <img src="" /><img src="" />
```

This removes the spacing to the left and right of the images, but as you can see in the example, the spacing below the images remains..

Is there anything that can be done about that?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: "for whatever reason" Because whitespace is part of inline flow.

Comment: @BoltClock - right, but I removed it, so why are there vertical gaps? Is this because of line-height or something like that? Hmm.. Testing.

Comment: line-height: 0 has no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EwtaC/2/

Add:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Images get aligned to baseline by default. Either you display them as block and float them or need to set a proper vertical alignment.

Comment: OMG, I never thought it was that simple. Earlier I used to display those elements as block and used other hacks to display them inline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inline-block, have you tried just floating the images:

```
img { float: left; }
```

Seems to work for me

Comment: Legitimate solution but floating has a whole new bag of tricks. :/

Answer (score -1):

you can also do

```
body
{
    line-height:0px;
}
```