# Divs with display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have two similar divs which are beside each other. But there is white space in between which I cannot remove?

My html as below

```
<div class="model-box" style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:98px;height:30px;">   
</div>
<div class="model-box" style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:98px;height:30px;">   
</div>
```

the fiddle as below

http://jsfiddle.net/xJW7G/

Why is this so?

Thanks in advance for the help?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=white+space+inline+block

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18987811/34397 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7432483/34397 http://stackoverflow.com/q/16678929/34397 http://stackoverflow.com/q/16935922/34397 http://stackoverflow.com/q/11982197/34397

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: -1 for lack of basic research; +1 for well-asked question

Comment: HAHA nice. just found the solution as well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The question is "Why?", not "How do I fix it?"

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the white-space character in between the divs, you could just get rid of it, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xJW7G/1/, or comment it out e.g.

```
<div class="model-box" style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:98px;height:30px;">   
</div><!--
--><div class="model-box" style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:98px;height:30px;">   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo might want to use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xJW7G/7/)**

Answer (score -1):

Add this css style to your seccond div

```
margin:0 0 0 -6px;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coscho/xJW7G/2/)